# INSERT INTO table DEFAULT(key_col) inserts zero?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have this primary key column in `tbl`:

```
`id` INT(5) unsigned NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

When I run the query below, zero is inserted instead of the next auto increment number:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl` (id, col1, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT(id), "value 1", ...)
```

The funny thing is, this behaviour is recent, making me wonder what setting I might have altered to result in this.

The first thing I considered was `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`. I have added this to the `sql_mode` in the configuration file, and now this is what it is: `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`
.

I know that when `DEFAULT(id)` is replaced by `NULL`, the auto number is generated as expected; but as it is now, my application produces the former rather than the latter.

My questions are:

1. Is there a setting that might allow `DEFAULT(id)` to generate the
       next auto number?
2. What other alteration in application environment could have led to this?

I ask these because this behaviour (insertion of zero) was not the case until recently.

Comment: Why do you need DEFAULT(id)?? Can't you omit it so the field will get the auto increment value?

Comment: what mysql version you using?

Comment: @user3571366: I could omit, but that would then require considerable modification to the application. If I could avoid it, that'd be better.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta: MySQL version is 5.6.23-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I realized that this behavior changes according to SQL options, not exactly sure which one, but `insert into table values (DEFAULT)` inserts zero with some options and inserts 1 (or next AI value) for others. Strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not supply the id as a column for an `auto_increment` PK column. You are just asking for trouble when you do. Perhaps a driver got updated on some layer. When you do it the way you were, trouble will come a knockin'   And it did.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable999
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    colC int not null
);

insert myTable999(thing,colC) values ('fish',5),('mustard',11),('gators',-12);

select * from myTable999;
+----+---------+------+
| id | thing   | colC |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | fish    |    5 |
|  2 | mustard |   11 |
|  3 | gators  |  -12 |
+----+---------+------+
```

You can adhere to the manual, or roll the dice. [Here is the Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html). Look at the first example.

Comment: He says it's from his application. He wants to keep it the same and get the auto increment to work as usual.

Comment: He can un-do all his system updates to make his application, as you say,  work the way it did before (using risky methods). Or he can do it the right way. Full refund if he is unhappy with my Answer.

Comment: @Drew: I appreciate your answer, and I know it'd work neat. But as I explained already, the DB code is produced by a complex application. I could decide to modify the application, but wouldn't if it could be made to work. Morever, why was it working well for years?

Comment: There are many layers of code between the app (let's for kicks call it an EXE) and the db. A layer changed. And since we are saying EXE, how many times have updates done un-do's to those things that work. Regardless of OS.